# Get ShockWaveFlash Memory use

Tags: c#, forms, flash, shockwave

I have a Shockwave Flash object on my form and I wont to see how much memory its using as well as other information regarding performance.

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add such imports to your project:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.system.System;
```

And then go trough Capabilities and System class properties and methods to get different system info (for example `System.freeMemory`). But you won't get much because of different flash restrictions.

Comment: Anywhere you want (create some method for getting system info), you didn't provide any code with your question, so I can't tell you anything.